# Is there a word that means "to cause (an image) to appear in the air" like a hologram?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that means "to cause (an image) to appear in the air" like a hologram? By image I mean a 2d image and not a 3d image like a hologram, but I don't mind if the word doesn't distinguish which kind of image. Is there any such word? I know that project means "to cause (an image) to appear on a surface", but I can't think of a word that means "to cause (an image) to appear in the air".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can also say "project" with this meaning, when a hologram is being used, one is said to project it. One can also speak of "displaying" the image, but would need to qualify that with "in space" or some similar phrase to have the specific meaning you want.

If the image is the result of a **mental** operation rather than a physical one, one could be said to "envision" something, or to "visualize" it. I would not use either word for a hologram-like physical process.

I cannot think of a specific term with exactly the meaning described in the question.

Answer (score -3):

mirage (which is more the image itself rather than the cause, but it's all I've got)

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for your answer. Your answer has been flagged by the system because it's short, and as you can see it's already been voted down by somebody. This community values well thought out answers that help the learner to understand and speak English better. I would suggest you explain what a mirage is, how the word is normally used, etc. If one word is all you have it's usually best not to answer, but I expect you can do better with a little extra effort. You can edit your answer and then you might get some up votes to put it back in the black.